# Relation of div - parent / child / independent

Tags: html

I'm doing a simple exercise and a question came up about parent / child divs. I wonder why does it look like when inspecting like "srch" is a child of "logo"? Since I have a closing div under my "logo" I thought "srch" instead would be child of the body element?

What have I gotten wrong?
Grateful for help!

**Please see attached:**
[image]

```html
<div id="logo">
    <img src="googlelogo.png"
</div>

<div id="srch">
    <input type="search" id="search">
</div>
<br />
<br />
```

Comment: you have missed your image closing tag

Comment: the reason is that the html is malformed because of the missing > on the img tag. is that on purpose?

Comment: I think you should close your 'img' tag too `<img src="...." />`

Comment: Judging from the screenshot, it looks like the `< div>` after your `img` tag should be `</div>` in order to properly close your logo div

Comment: @Alex there already is a closing div tag after the image tag? (Looking at the code supplied rather than how chrome renders it because of the broken image tag)

Comment: @Pete not according to the screenshot from the Chrome inspector, take a look

Comment: See the bit in brackets in my comment above @Alex

Comment: Apologise for this. Thanks. The broken img tag was the issue.